# Possible to restrict PostgreSQL security definer function to RLS use?

Tags: postgresql, row-level-security, supabase

I am using RLS (Row Level Security) with supabase.io for a "serverless" application.  I have to use various security definer functions for RLS policies.  These are still callable through supabase's rpc library.  Is there anyway to limit calling these functions to either the admin (me) or when used as part of a RLS policy?

e.g.:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_bases_editable_or_viewable_for_user(user_id uuid, allow_edit bool)
returns setof bigint as $$
  select base_id
  from access_controls
  where access_controls.user_id = $1 AND ($2 AND access_controls.access_level = 'editor') OR access_controls.access_level = 'viewer';
$$ stable language sql security definer;

CREATE policy "Users can read bases they are editors or viewers of"
on public.bases
for select using ( bases.id in (get_bases_editable_or_viewable_for_user(auth.uid(), true)) );
```

`get_bases_editable_or_viewable_for_user` allows any user, once they have another user's UID, to find out the UIDs that this user has access to as an editor or viewer:

```js
supabase.rpc(
  "get_bases_editable_or_viewable_for_user",
  { user_id: "dddddde6-1111-4bdf-aaaa-33336ccc31ee", allow_edit: true }
)
.then(console.log) // => bad
```

Minimising opportunities for leaking information is always important for maximising the security of an application and the privacy of its users.

Comment: Rather then repeat it here,  look at the **Notes** section at [CREATE POLICY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createpolicy.html). Short version the policies run with the rights of the user running the query. So if users other then admin are going to run queries you can't restrict access too much.

Comment: The `USING` clause of a policy definition must return a `boolean`. Such a function will not leak information it shouldn't.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe sorry I had some how managed to paste some broken code.  I've fixed it now.  I can't see how it's possible to move the `bases.id` into the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot restrict permissions on the function in that way, since the user that runs the query must be able to execute it.

I see two ways to improve that:

- Omit the first parameter from the function, so that it only gives results for the current user. Then nobody can see information for other users.
- In addition to the above, you could pass `bases.id` as a function parameter and have the function return a `boolean`. Then you cannot get a list, but the performance may suffer, since the function has to be called for each row.

Comment: I just tried your first suggestion and that seems to be working.  Thank you very much. Related Q&A on supabase: https://github.com/supabase/supabase/discussions/3269#discussioncomment-1361503

Comment: Apologies if this is noise as I'm not 100% certain how useful this information is for general PostgreSQL users but when working with RPC on Supabase.io you can create a private schema, define the functions there and use them from the public RLS policies: https://github.com/supabase/supabase/discussions/3269#discussioncomment-1366674

Comment: You can call the function even if it is in a different schema. Perhaps your API makes that impossible, but in general that won't help.